# Ubuntu 16.10 with VirtualBox: Host cannot access audio cd in physical drive

Tags: virtualbox, 16.10, dvd-audio

I have a Ubuntu 16.10 (upgraded from a fresh 16.04) stationary computer - host - with a physical dvd-burner drive.   I also have the latest version of VirtualBox installed for work I need to do with Windows and various Linux-versions as guests.

Now I would like to listen to audio cd's in the host dvd-drive, but the various audio cd utilities in Ubuntu (the host) does not recognize the audio cd and give vague indications that there is no media in the drive at all.  This might be because VirtualBox intercepts the drive in order to present it to its guests and it is only presented to the host as a data-only drive?

I would like to fix this.  I do not have any need for the physical drive inside virtualbox, so telling VirtualBox to leave the drive alone would be fine.  The "Passthrough" option in the VirtualBox GUI does not immediately remedy this in the host.

Am I on the right track or barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: I don't think so. Is it an USB DVD-burner ? if yes, and it is explicilty configured in passtrhough mode, then you will see the behavior you describe but otherwise I wonder how is this possible. Do you have the problem when virtualbox does not run ??

Comment: No, it is a traditional disk drive (eSATA I believe).  I tested this right after startup before invoking the VirtualBox GUI or starting any virtual machines.  My guess would be that the VirtualBox kernel drivers on the Ubuntu host are doing this.